# Revert Convert Charset - Saving error

Tags: html, character-encoding

Sorry, if it doesn't related much to programming, but I think it's the best platform posting since many of you are likely to know my answer as you may work with different locales.

I have a webpage saved originally in `big5` charset, but accidentally saved it as a `utf-8` charset document. Is there any method converting it back?

I checked on Google but can't seem to find any useful information. I can choose to save the `.html` in any format but please help me with my encoding.

Essentially, I want a way to **reverse transcode** character sets.

Comment: That depends on what exactly happened. Did the editor (or whatever) correctly *read* the file as Big5 and then correctly re-save it as UTF-8? Then you should have a good UTF-8 file. Or did the editor misinterpret the Big5 file as UTF-8 (producing garbage) and then saved it as UTF-8? Then there may be no way back. Or did it misinterpret the Big5 file in some other encoding? Then there *may* be a way back.

Comment: @deceze the editor misinterpret the Big5 file as UTF-8, but couldn't there be reverse engineering?

Comment: There's probably no way to do it. The two encodings are incompatible in a way that most data has probably been discarded. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for details.